# Is there a fast way to nest a formula or fill formula arguments efficiently in Excel?

Tags: excel, excel-formula

Consider the below formula:
=CHOOSE(index_num, value1, [value2], ...)
=CONCATENATE(text1, [text2], ...)

I am seeking methods for creating a formula, such as this, which can accept up to [254 arguments](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/choose-function-fc5c184f-cb62-4ec7-a46e-38653b98f5bc) , or other formulas that can accept more than 1 argument to have those arguments filled quickly.

For example, there are [195 countries](https://www.cia.gov/library/publications/the-world-factbook/geos/xx.html) in the world today.

The current method employed by many excel users would be to manually type every country into the formula or to create a list of countries in a sheet and then to reference each country by clicking cells directly.

What is the fastest way to hard code every country into the arguments list of the Excel CHOOSE or the CONCATENATE function without using VBA or other coding techniques?

So an idea is to go from
=CHOOSE(Index_Num,A1,B1,C1,...

to

=CHOOSE(Index_Num,"Afghanistan","Albania","Algeria",...
or
=CHOOSE(Index_Num,IF(x,y,z),Sum(a,b,c),Average(a,b,c),...

The concept is to fill the formula arguments with a string of choice over using cell references or individual cells.

Is there a fast way to nest a formula or fill formula arguments efficiently in Excel?

As the title includes information about nesting formulas, if the solution can be applied for a list of countries but not a list of formulas, please include a reason why.

Please note, the answer is not seeking VBA/coding solutions, however, they may be included.

Edit:
Edited for clarity.

Comment: Why "hard code"?  What is wrong with refering to a range and using INDEX/MATCH instead of CHOOSE, the limit there is the number of rows.

Comment: @ScottCraner Well, because CHOOSE was used as an example. I'll need to edit the title question into the body of the question to clarify that the function being filled is irrelevant. It isn't about finding an item in a list.

Comment: Please use a real life example.  What you want to achieve with an actual formula.  It is hard to understand.  Please show what your inputs would be and expected outputs.

Comment: This is an interesting question from a theoretical point of view, though not from the practical. Although it is true that many functions, such as CHOOSE, allow for a large number of arguments, I don't recall an example in which use of such a function with many arguments cannot be replaced by one with few arguments and which references a small number of ranges (or arrays). Not only does the latter set-up make for more concise formulas, it also has the benefit of not suffering from the inflexibility of the former's hard-coded arguments.

Comment: Look into TEXTJOIN, copy and paste the output into the formula.

Comment: @XORLX I agree that this has extremely limited practical uses compared to alternatives, but every tool can be useful at some point.

Comment: I cannot agree with you re CHOOSE, though for CONCATENATE I take your point, that function being something of an exception (thankfully redundant with the newer CONCAT and TEXTJOIN). I always used to 1) Paste the desired entries into a contiguous, vertical range of cells, e.g. A1:A200; 2) Type the formula =TRANSPOSE(A1:A200) into a random cell somewhere; 3) Go into the formula bar as if to edit it, highlight the entire formula and press F9; 4) Remove the curly brackets at either end of the resulting array; 5) Type CONCATENATE( after the equals sign and press ENTER.

Comment: @XORLX something tells me that is the answer to this question.

Answer (score 0):

I am not exactly sure what you are trying to achieve with the `CHOOSE` function.
To lookup values in a list of countries, you could use `LOOKUP` or a combination of `INDEX` and `MATCH`.

[Interesting article](https://professor-excel.com/when-to-use-vlookup-sumifs-or-indexmatch-in-excel/) with a comparison of SUMIF , LOOKUP , and INDEX/MATCH.

But as a theoretical exercise, and taking your example about adding 192 arguments to a function, I would just create the list of arguments for the function separately in Excel, using text functions, combining the list of countries with the " and ; . I would as such construct the argument of the function, and at the end take the outcome and just copy/paste this as the argument of the function.